# How can I compare the values of 6 columns to another column in my DataFrame and create another column with the results?

Tags: python, database, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to python with no programming experience and i could not find the answer from previous posts. I am trying to make a table that compares the value of my columns to another column which happens to be the max value of the other columns. I am trying to find a way to tell which of my categories has the highest number for each row and then append the name of that "winner column" into a list to later create a new column.

I tried to use a for loop with a conditional statement but it doesn't seem to be working (not in my current code).

```html
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import io
import sys

#the code that opens my raw data
df = pd.read_csv(Desktop\Python Files)
short_desc = (df['Target Short Description'])
identifier = (df['NumberID'])

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df)  
sr = pd.Series(short_desc) 
idx = [identifier]
sr.index = idx

k_specialty = ['specialty','services']
k_his = ['communication','management,','enterprise resource','software','data','marketing','supply chain' ]
k_alr = ['housing','home','rehab','rehabilitation','addiction','drug abuse','substance abuse','alcohol addiction','assisted living','senior living']
k_ach = ['acute']
k_mc = ['integrative health','integrated health','integration']
k_hs = ['staffing','Staffing','human resource','Human resource',"HR","hr"]
k_ds = ['diagnostic','diagnosis','testing','test']

k_specialty1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_specialty]) #Specialty Services
k_his1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_his]) #Healthcare Information Systems
k_alr1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_alr]) #Assisted Living/Rehabilitation
k_ach1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_ach]) #Acute-Care Hopsitals
k_mc1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_mc]) #Managed Care
k_hs1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_hs]) #Healthcare Staffing
k_ds1 = '|'.join([f'(?i){word}' for word in k_ds]) #Diagnostic Services

rDiagnosticServices = sr.str.contains(pat = k_ds1)

#sr['count'] = sr['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_ds1, re.I) <--- Tried this, Does not work.

indexeddata =pd.DataFrame(sr)
indexeddata

#indexeddata['Count']=indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_ds1) #Count Function that creates a new column
count_k_ds1 = indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_ds1)
count_k_hs1 = indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_hs1)
count_k_mc1 = indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_mc1)
count_k_ach1 = indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_ach1)
count_k_alr1 = indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_alr1)
count_k_his1 = indexeddata['Target Short Description'].str.count(k_his1)

count_indexeddata = [count_k_ds1,
    count_k_hs1,
    count_k_mc1,
    count_k_ach1,
    count_k_alr1,
    count_k_his1]

goodarray = np.array(count_indexeddata)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
dirtdf = pd.DataFrame(count_indexeddata)


type_new = pd.Series([])

dirtdf.index = ['Diagnostic Services','Healthcare Staffing',
'Managed Care','Acute-Care Hopsitals','Assisted Living/Rehabilitation','Healthcare Information Systems']
good_df = dirtdf.T
#good_df.insert(6,'Best fit',best_fit_desc)

max_df = pd.DataFrame(good_df.max(axis = 1))
max_df.columns = ['Max Value']
good_df.insert(6,'Max Value', max_df)

best_fit_desc = []
c = np.where((good_df['Diagnostic Services'] == good_df['Max Value']) & good_df['Diagnostic Services'] != 0)
print(c)
```

I am getting this output:
(array([  9,  42,  47,  57,  62,  63,  90,  91, 116, 129, 136, 201, 222],
      dtype=int64),)

Also I feel that my code is way to large for a simple function. I would appreciate if any of you have any suggestions added to you input.

Thank you!

This is what my dataframe looks like][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBFte.png)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your data are in a pandas dataframe, you can create the desired column "max_values" with:

```
df['max_values'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```